# Boot Camp can't detect my macOS volume

Tags: keyboard, windows, bootcamp, partition, startup

Recently, I installed Windows 8.1 Pro on my MacBook Air (Early 2015, 13 inch).

Windows 8.1 worked fine for 2-3 days, but the drivers for trackpad and keyboard started to behave erratically and suddenly stopped working. I found out they weren't available in Control Panel. Bootcamp is upto date as well.

I tried to boot back into macOS but Boot Camp couldn't locate the macOS boot volume.

I restarted using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key but my Mac booted from the Windows partition. Before, I used to hear a chime and see the Apple logo after startup, but now my Mac directly starts up in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening Boot Camp Control Panel in Control Panel of Windows 8.1 (or via Boot Camp icon in System Tray right next to system time on Task Bar's botom right corner) and checking Startup Disk tab for macOS volume? If it's not there, you're in trouble! If it's there, select it and use Restart button.

[image: Here's what to look for]

Comment: Yes, I've tried opening bootcamp control panel, MacOS Volume isn't there.

Comment: Add screen shot of your internal disk in Disk Management to your question or here in comment. Use Win+R > `diskmgmt.msc` to launch it.

Comment: Plz see the below image                                                          
https://imgur.com/ETgGp82

Comment: Good news is your macOS partition seems to be still present and hopefully is still good! Check answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99289/), please, there're too many options to double-check so I'm referencing different question. However please don't try installing rEFIt as it's suggested in the answers, try all other options. If it won't help I'll guide you how to install rEFInd+ which is a fixed updated rebuild. Please let me know if it helps so I could add it to initial answer to your question!